# Strange RoR problem; googlebot gets error, human sees page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I maintain a Ruby-on-Rails website (actually running JRuby 1.5.5, Rails version 2.3.10) and am seeing something fairly strange. A certain controller action is causing an exception in the logs, when accessed by a search engine bot:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (can't convert nil into String) on line #14 of app/vie
ws/scenarios/show_send_message.rhtml:
11:   <% if ! is_logged_in? %>
12:     <p>Your email (optional, used to contact you if necessary):<br /><%= tex
t_field_tag 'user_email', @user_email || '', :size => 50 %>
13:     <% if ! is_human? %>
14:       <%= show_simple_captcha %>
15:     <% end %>
16:   <% end %>
17:   <p><%= submit_tag 'Send' %>
```

... However, when I [view the page as a human](http://greenfootgallery.org/scenarios/1764/show_send_message), it works fine. "show_simple_captcha" is a method from a plugin, and it can't return nil.

Does anyone have any idea why RoR would respond differently to a bot than it would to a real browser? I'm not so much looking for the answer to the problem as I am a way to proceed with debugging, but I'll gladly accept the former.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace or is that it?

Comment: @Sam, there's no javascript in the captcha, and anyway that doesn't explain why I'm getting this error on the server side.

Comment: @rwilliams, The stack trace is two lines long, and really doesn't help. Honestly.

Comment: If you can emulate a bot somehow I'd start throwing debugger statements in the plugin and see where it's messing up

Comment: @rwilliams, seems I can get the same result using wget. I guess I can try the approach you suggested, thanks; I'm still hoping for an "ah ha!" moment though.

Comment: Good luck. My guess is that it's a bug in the plugin.

Comment: Most likely show_simple_captcha has some logic internally that tries to take a value that google request doesn't provide, and use it as a string. This doesn't mean the value actually be returned. In fact, it definitely has nothing to do with return value of `show_simple_captcha`, because `<%= nil %>` would've worked. (`<%=  %>` automatically calls `#to_s` on result of its expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to view the page, I got 500 too. There's a big chance something is wrong with your code. For example, you expect session or cookie variable to be set, when it's not.

Comment: If you are using Rails 2, add "Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers" to environment.rb and see the backtrace. The exception is probably happening in the plugin you're using, but you can't see the stack trace since Rails tries to clean it up and show you only the lines from your app code. I hate this feature and I disable it right away in all my Rails projects.

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the useful tip. It turns out that the captcha generator uses the session id, however the session id can apparently be nil (think this might have changed between Rails versions). This caused an exception in the plugin, which I couldn't see because of the filtering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the above error message and code snippet, but is it possible that this action is making the assumption that you are logged in to the site?

My first thought is that the application has some type of a state (cookie, session, etc) and that when you are visiting the website you already have established your state with the app and therefore you do not experience any problems. The Google Bot on the other hand, may just be jumping right to this page and will lack any state your site might assume was already setup.

Another thing that pops to my mind, is the captcha control could be making some rendering decisions based on user agent. Perhaps the user agent the Google Bot is using isn't liked by your captcha control. Try getting one of those Firefox plugins that lets you change your user agent, and set it to the value you see in your logs. Hit your website and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have checked the code for the show_simple_captch method and it really can't return nil. (And it doesn't care about user agents; it's really not that complex.)

Comment: (And, no, it doesn't assumed you're logged in; a logged-in user shouldn't see the captcha, when I'm not logged in I do see the captcha as I should).

Comment: you are correct, its probably not a user agent issue. I visited the website in chrome and it crashed. Something is wrong with this page even for non robots.

Comment: @davmac, care to elaborate on how I would navigate to this page? I made it so far as to view a scenario, but at the bottom I see a message saying "If you want to leave a comment on this scenario, you must first log in." is a comment what I want to leave?

Comment: From the scenario page click the "Report this scenario" (as broken or inappropriate) link, just below the applet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can emulate a bot, start debugging the plugin. My guess is that it's a bug with the plugin itself and not your app.

Answer (score 0):

I too am facing the same problem. On investigating the plugin, I could understand that while rendering the page on which there's captcha, the 'simple_captcha_controller' is called for rendering the captcha-image (look at the 'src' attribute of the captcha image). In this url, the param 'simple_captcha_key' is also passed. The key is calculated and is passed as a param to simple_captcha_controller'. The key-value pair is stored in the table 'simple_captcha_date'. So, when a human is viewing the form, the key is pre-calculated(and has a value) and sent to the 'simple_captcha_controller' and hence we don't see the problem. However, when a bot is 'viewing', the mechanism of which I don't quite understand, the key passed to the 'simple_captcha_controller' doesn't have a value in the 'simple_captcha_data' table and returns nil. ('SimpleCaptchaData.get_data(key).value' in simple_captcha_config.rb returns nil)
The error can be reproduced if arbitrary keys are passed.